# Maximum number of CommonPrefixes and MaxKeys in S3 list objects

Tags: amazon-s3

So the question is simple, what is the biggest number of CommongPrefixes displayed when you list s3 objects, and what is the biggest MaxKeys. Default is 1000.
[Amazon s3 api / bucket get](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question, maximum number of CommonPrefixes and MaxKeys is 1000.

Caution, TOGETHER 1000.
This means that you can have 0 Keys displayed, and maximum 1000 CommonPrefixes or
990 Keys displayed, and maximum 10 CommonPrefixes